# How to define polyhedra?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

Wikipedia does not provide a concise definition of "polyhedron" in $\mathbb R^n$. What is the "best" - in whatever sense - definition of this class of objects?

I am interested in a definition where there are finitely many faces whilst the polyhedron may be unbounded. This includes convex polyhedra $\mathcal P$ in $\mathbb R^n$, which can be be defined as

$ x \in \mathcal P \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \forall 1 \leq i \leq m : a_i^t \cdot x \leq b_i$

where $a_i, \dots, a_m, b \in \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Union of convex polyhedra? Maybe you want it connected, or maybe not. Ah, and it seems to be that the language is 'polytope' for the thing in arbitrary dimensions, 'polygon' in $2$-D, and 'polyhedron' in $3$-D.

Comment: In some contexts a polyhedron is considered to be a region in $\mathbb R^3$ bounded by polygons.  But in other contexts, it is a metric space made of polygons with each edge of one glued to an equally long edge of another.  The latter definition is enough to prove Descartes' result that the sum of the defects is $4\pi$ if the polyhedron is homeomorphic to a sphere.  (The defect at a point is the amount by which the circumference of a small circle about that point falls short of $2\pi$; the defect is negative if the circumference exceeds $2\pi$.)  Can every polyhedron (in that sense) that is...

Comment: ...homeomorphic to a sphere be realized as the boundary of some region in $\mathbb R^3$?  I don't know.  In the latter sense, one can speak, for example, of a polyhedron homeomorphic to a projective plane (the example I know of has one regular hexagonal face and three square faces).

Answer (score 1):

In general, (the interior of) a polyhedron is defined as a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, bounded by a finite number of hyperplanes. It decomposes the space into two regions. 
If none of the bounding hyperplanes crosses the interior, we then have a convex polyhedron, which can thus be expressed as the intersection of a finite number of half-spaces bounded by hyperplanes: $$ P_{conv}=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} : \ xA \leq b, \ A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}, \ b \in \mathbb{R}^{m}\}.$$
Note that some authors call a convex polyhedron a polytope, others use polytope to refer to a bounded polyhedron. Moreover, polytope can also be the general term of the sequence: point, segment, polygon, polyhedron,... where in this case a polyhedron refers only to the 3 dimensional objects of this series.

A good reference on this topic is the book "Regular polytopes" by Coxeter.